# Media Foundation in plain C, finding the IID

Tags: c, uuid, guid, ms-media-foundation

When using the C api for media foundation there is no `IID_PPV_ARGS()` macro that can help you find the `IID` for the object you are trying to create. Below is the Sample code for C++ that I am trying to mimic in C:

```c
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT32 count = 0;
IMFTransform *ppDecoder = NULL;
IMFActivate **ppActivate = NULL;

MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO info = { 0 };
info.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Audio;
info.guidSubtype = MFAudioFormat_AAC;

hr = MFTEnumEx(
    MFT_CATEGORY_AUDIO_DECODER,
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_LOCALMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER,
    &info,      // Input type
    NULL,       // Output type
    &ppActivate,
    &count
    );
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && count == 0)
{
    hr = MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND;
}
hr = ppActivate[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&ppDecoder));
```

Where the last line is the issue, `IID_PPV_ARGS` does not exist when working with c. I found a answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514232/media-foundation-using-c-instead-of-c) that helped me understand how to produce the parameters that ActivateObject needs in c:

```c
    hr = ppActivate[0]->lpVtbl->ActivateObject(ppActivate[0], &IID_Foo, (IUnknown**) ppDecoder);
```

The problem is that I do not know what IID type I should use, hence the `IID_Foo`. From the other thread there was a straightforward mapping from the type `IMFMediaSource` to `IID_IMFMediaSource`. But I found no such thing for `IMFTransform`, nor to any decoder class. Is there a good place where to look for these IID's?

I found that `IID_Foo` types are defined in mfidl.h and I also found [this](https://github.com/CMCHTPC/MediaFoundation/blob/master/Units/CMC.MFIdl.pas) file which might be old but gives a quick overview of the available IID definitions and I found none that seems right for me.

**So my question** really is how to go about finding the needed IID's in general, and more specifically for IMFTransform.

Comment: So why not `IID_IMFTransform`?

Comment: @RomanR. ... declared in `mftransform.h`.

Comment: I made the misstake to assume all IID_Foo types were defined in mfidl.h where I found a lot of IID's were defined. IID_IMFTransform was defined elsewhere and hence I did not find it. Thanks!