# GetOutputStatus says output is ready, ProcessOutput says NEED_MORE_INPUT

Tags: c, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I am getting stuck in this situation where I get conflicting information:

```c
hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessInput(pDecoder, dwInputStreamID, pSample, dwFlags);
if (FAILED(hr) ... )
//ProcessInput went well, no warnings from here.

hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetOutputStatus(pDecoder, &dwFlags);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        if (dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY) {
            // I get to here, sample is ready, yay!
        }
    }
dwFlags = 0;

hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetInputStatus(pDecoder, 0, &dwFlags);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    if (dwFlags == MFT_INPUT_STATUS_ACCEPT_DATA) {
        //...
    } else {
        // we go here, input does not accept more data it seems.
        // Sounds ok, we read the output that is ready and then we fill in more
    }

}
dwFlags = 0;

hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessOutput(pDecoder,
    dwFlags,
    1,
    pOutputSamples,
    &pdwStatus
);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT) {
        // Ok, but why did GetOutputStatus say we were ready then?
    }
}

// Calling GetOutputStatus to see whats going on
hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetOutputStatus(pDecoder, &dwFlags);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    if (dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY) {
        // nope.
    } else {
        // Now dwFlags is 0.
    }
}

hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetInputStatus(pDecoder, 0, &dwFlags);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    if (dwFlags == MFT_INPUT_STATUS_ACCEPT_DATA) {
        // this time we go here, we can now give more input again.
        // but we got no data from ProcessOutput
    } else {
        //...
    }

}
dwFlags = 0;
```

Looking at the data media sample I've sent to processOutput to be filled in it simply writes a null terminator `'\0'` in the beginning of the buffer but otherwise it does not write any output.

[GetOutputStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696269(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If the method returns the **MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY** flag, **it
>   means you can generate one or more output samples by calling
>   IMFTransform::ProcessOutput.**
>
> ...
>
> After the client has set valid media
>   types on all of the streams, the MFT should always be in one of two
>   states: **Able to accept more input, or able to produce more output.**

I got no errors earlier while setting up the decoders input and output streams so Im thinking the streams should be good. And I've not got any warnings while sending in the input media either so Im thinking I should be in a valid state. But the behaviour does not seem to match what I think the documentation is suggesting. Also I only have 1 input and 1 output stream if that is of interest.

So how could this happen? I have conflicting information from the tool. Is the data ready but I am reading it wrong, or is there something else going on?

## Edit:

There were a few comments asking for more information, and one asking for a minimum complete example so I decided to try it out. Below is a small c program that runs all the things I run and it simulates my environment by reading input from a file and sending it in the same way I am getting my data. I have striped out almost all error handling, removed helper functions and hardcoded a few things. This program reproduces the issue. I am running this in Visual Studio 2015.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//windows media foundation test
#include <windows.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mferror.h>

int chunk_handler(unsigned char* pBuf, unsigned short length);

IMFTransform *pDecoder = NULL;
DWORD dwInputStreamID;
DWORD dwOutputStreamID;


// inspierd by FindDecoder here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701774(v=vs.85).aspx
HRESULT FindDecoder(
    IMFTransform **ppDecoder    // Receives a pointer to the decoder.
)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT32 count = 0;

    IMFActivate **ppActivate = NULL;

    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO inputType = { 0 };

    inputType.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Audio;
    inputType.guidSubtype = MFAudioFormat_AAC;

    hr = MFTEnumEx(
        MFT_CATEGORY_AUDIO_DECODER,
        MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_LOCALMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER,
        &inputType,      // Input type
        NULL,       // Output type
        &ppActivate,
        &count
    );

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && count == 0)
    {
        hr = MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Create the first decoder in the list.

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ppActivate[0]->lpVtbl->ActivateObject(ppActivate[0], &IID_IMFTransform, (IUnknown**)ppDecoder);
    }

    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ppActivate[i]->lpVtbl->Release(ppActivate[i]);
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(ppActivate);

    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    UINT32 samplesPerSec = 44100;
    UINT32 bitsPerSample = 16;
    UINT32 cChannels = 2;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);

    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    DWORD dwFlags = MFSTARTUP_FULL;
    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION, dwFlags);

    // Create decoder
    pDecoder = NULL;
    hr = FindDecoder(&pDecoder);

    // Create input and output audio types
    IMFMediaType *pMediaIn = NULL;        // Pointer to an encoded audio type.
    IMFMediaType *pMediaOut = NULL;       // Receives a matching PCM audio type.

    /* Create pMediaIn */

    // Calculate derived values.
    UINT32 blockAlign = cChannels * (bitsPerSample / 8);
    UINT32 bytesPerSecond = blockAlign * samplesPerSec;

    // Create the empty media type.
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaIn);

    // Set attributes on the type.
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetGUID(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, &MFMediaType_Audio);
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetGUID(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &MFAudioFormat_AAC);
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AAC_AUDIO_PROFILE_LEVEL_INDICATION, 0x2a); // value can be found in my onenote, (AAC Profile, Level 4)
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AAC_PAYLOAD_TYPE, 3); // (LOAS/LATM)
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, bitsPerSample);
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, cChannels);
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, samplesPerSec);

    // blockAlign, bytesPerSecond and independent samples were commented out previously
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, blockAlign);
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, bytesPerSecond);
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);


    //first 12 bytes:
    //wPayloadType  = 0 (raw AAC)
    //wAudioProfileLevelIndication  = 0x29 (AAC Profile, Level 2)
    //wStructType  = 0
    //  The last two bytes of MF_MT_USER_DATA contain the value of AudioSpecificConfig(), as defined by MPEG - 4.
    // 00010 0100 0010 000
    //AudioSpecificConfig.audioObjectType = 2 (AAC LC) (5 bits)
    //AudioSpecificConfig.samplingFrequencyIndex = 4 (4 bits) (44100hz)
    //AudioSpecificConfig.channelConfiguration = 2 (4 bits)
    //GASpecificConfig.frameLengthFlag = 0 (1 bit)
    //GASpecificConfig.dependsOnCoreCoder = 0 (1 bit)
    //GASpecificConfig.extensionFlag = 0 (1 bit)
    UINT8 audioSpecificConfig[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x2a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12, 0x10 }; 
    hr = pMediaIn->lpVtbl->SetBlob(pMediaIn, &MF_MT_USER_DATA, audioSpecificConfig, 14);


    /* Create pMediaOut */

    // Create the empty media type.
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaOut);

    // Set attributes on the type.
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetGUID(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, &MFMediaType_Audio);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetGUID(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &MFAudioFormat_PCM);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, cChannels);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, samplesPerSec);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, blockAlign);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, bytesPerSecond);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, bitsPerSample);
    hr = pMediaOut->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pMediaOut, &MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);

    // Figure out streamcounts and ID's
    DWORD inputStreamCount = 0;
    DWORD outputStreamCount = 0;

    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetStreamCount(pDecoder, &inputStreamCount, &outputStreamCount); // both StreamCounts == 1

    DWORD dwInputID[1] = { 0 }; //hardcoded
    DWORD dwOutputID[1] = { 0 }; //hardcoded

    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetStreamIDs(pDecoder, inputStreamCount, dwInputID, outputStreamCount, dwOutputID);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (hr == E_NOTIMPL) {
            // This is expected and quite ok. 
        }
    }

    dwInputStreamID = dwInputID[0];
    dwOutputStreamID = dwOutputID[0];

    // configure decoder for the two audio types
    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->SetInputType(pDecoder, dwInputStreamID, pMediaIn, 0);
    dwFlags = 0;
    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->SetOutputType(pDecoder, dwOutputStreamID, pMediaOut, dwFlags);

    /*one time setup is now done.*/

    // simulate sending in the first couple of chunks that I can get while trying to decode audio

    // Reading this from file, again this is just read from a file in this example, in my real application I get the data sent to me in audio frame chunks.
    // For example the first "chunk" of data is:
    //  47fc 0000 b090 8003 0020 2066 0001 9800 0de1 2000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001c 

    errno_t err;
    FILE *file = NULL;
    fopen_s(&file, "input.txt", "rb");

    unsigned char line[10000]; //big enough
#define NR_OF_INPUTS 14
    //                           0   1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
    int sizes[NR_OF_INPUTS] = { 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 340, 708, 503, 477, 493, 499, 448, 640, 511}; // lengths of the data

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < NR_OF_INPUTS; i++) {
        fread(line, sizeof(char), sizes[i], file);

        printf("Input chunk number: %d\n", i);
        for (j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++) {
            printf(" %02x", line[j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

        chunk_handler(line, sizes[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

int chunk_handler(unsigned char* pBuf, unsigned short length) {

    const UINT SamplesPerSecond = 44100;
    const UINT ChannelCount = 2;
    const UINT SampleCount = length * ChannelCount;
    const UINT BitsPerSample = 16;
    const UINT BufferLength = BitsPerSample / 8 * ChannelCount * length;
    const LONGLONG sampleDuration = (long long)length * (long long)10000000 / SamplesPerSecond; // in hns (hecto nano second?) 0.000 000 1. (Duration of the sample, in 100-nanosecond units., see IMFSample)

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DWORD dwFlags = 0;

    /* Setup for processInput */

    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pInputBuffer = NULL;
    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(
        length,   // Amount of memory to allocate, in bytes.
        &pInputBuffer
    );
    BYTE *pData = NULL;

    hr = pInputBuffer->lpVtbl->Lock(pInputBuffer, &pData, NULL, NULL);
    memcpy_s(pData, length, pBuf, length);
    hr = pInputBuffer->lpVtbl->SetCurrentLength(pInputBuffer, length);
    hr = pInputBuffer->lpVtbl->Unlock(pInputBuffer);


    hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    hr = pSample->lpVtbl->AddBuffer(pSample, pInputBuffer);
    //hr = pSample->lpVtbl->SetUINT32(pSample, &MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity, TRUE);


    /* Setup for processOutput */
#define SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER 1
    MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER pOutputSamples[SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER];
    MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO streamInfo = { 0,0,0 };
    MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO *pStreamInfo = &streamInfo;
    DWORD pdwStatus = 0;

    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetOutputStreamInfo(pDecoder, dwOutputStreamID, pStreamInfo);
    IMFSample *pOutSample = NULL;
    DWORD minimumSizeOfBuffer = pStreamInfo->cbSize;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pOutputBuffer = NULL;

    // code checking for if MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLE and such, Turns out client (me) ne4ed to provide sample so lets do that

    // Create the media buffer.
    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(
        minimumSizeOfBuffer,   // Amount of memory to allocate, in bytes.
        &pOutputBuffer
    );
    hr = MFCreateSample(&pOutSample);
    hr = pOutSample->lpVtbl->AddBuffer(pOutSample, pOutputBuffer);

    pOutputSamples[0].pSample = pOutSample;
    pOutputSamples[0].dwStreamID = dwOutputStreamID;
    pOutputSamples[0].dwStatus = 0;
    pOutputSamples[0].pEvents = NULL;

    //INPUT
    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessInput(pDecoder, dwInputStreamID, pSample, dwFlags);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (hr == MF_E_NOTACCEPTING) {
            printf("Input cannot take more data\n");
        }
        printf("error in ProcessInput\n");
    }

    //OUTPUT
    hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessOutput(pDecoder,
        dwFlags,
        SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER,
        pOutputSamples,
        &pdwStatus
    );
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT) {
            // this is ok, just need to make more calls to ProcessInput
            printf("ProcessOutput needs more input\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("error in ProcessOutput\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The "file.txt" references in the code should contain the following inserted as hex:

```
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
```

The input file is also here:
http://filebin.ca/3DACc6lkf882/input.txt

## Edit 2:

Here is a sample from the MFTrace with some extra traces put in there:

```
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09829 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ ----------------------------------ProcessInput----------------------------------
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09832 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessInput @00000229F1932698 Stream ID 0, Sample @00000229F19D2160, Time 0ms, Duration 0ms, Buffers 1, Size 640B,
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09832 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessMessage @00000229F1932698 Message type=0x10000000 MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, param=00000000
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09832 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ GetOutputStatus says MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09833 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ GetInputStatus says does NOT accept data
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09834 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ ----------------------------------ProcessOutput----------------------------------
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09834 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessMessage @00000229F1932698 Message type=0x10000000 MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, param=00000000
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09835 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @00000229F1932698 failed hr=0xC00D6D72 MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09835 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ ProcessOutput needs more input
23816,3D70 10:43:31.09836 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ GetInputStatus says MFT_INPUT_STATUS_ACCEPT_DATA
```

Comment: What is the decoder? These also need to be written to the specification, if they enter an invalid state then so with the transform as a whole. I.e. you may have a buggy decoder.

Comment: Use the correct language tags! This is C++, not C.

Comment: @Olaf what do you base this being C++ on? This is pure C.

Comment: In terms of a workaround, just treat `GetInputStatus` as advisory. This is an optional function anyway (i.e. `E_NOTIMPL` is a valid return code) so you can simply not call it if you don't want to.

Comment: @AlexTelon: Read the documentation of `GetOutputStatus` you linked and the error-message. C does not support _methods_, nor is the method-notation ideomatic.

Comment: @Olaf, I can see where you are coming from. But I really am using plain C. The documentation is just not there for plain C so you have to use the C++ version. See this SO question for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514232/media-foundation-using-c-instead-of-c or search for [ms-media-foundation][c] here on SO and you will find there being many questions that use media foundation in C and not C++.

The source code for the library is filled with:
`#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(CINTERFACE)`

and

`#else  /* C style interface */`
so it is built for both languages.

Comment: @Olaf, COM defines both C and C++ bindings. C does not have a concept of interfaces and methods, but COM does. It's not incorrect to use the word "method" to refer to a method on a COM interface, even if you are calling it using the C binding.

Comment: @AlexTelon: To repeat: The error-message is clearly C++. It is **no way** C. And while `lpVtbl->GetInputStatus(...)` **could be** C if `GetInputStatus` is a function pointer, it more looks like C++, too. If not, it would have to be initialised. Nevertheless, either the C or the C++ tag is wrong, use the tag of the language you use, not both (with your last comment, I'm fine with either). And use the documentation for that language.

Comment: @Ben: That message is clearly not C and the code does smell like C++, not C. OP should use the correct documentation for the language he uses and pick one tag, any of the two would be fine. Nevertheless I suspect a [mcve] would be required.

Comment: @Ben, thanks! Yes I initially did not use `GetInputStatus` at all, but when I got into a situation where ProcessOutput always asked for more input no matter how much I sent to ProcessInput I tried to see if I could get more information from `GetInputStatus` and `GetOutputStatus` but they did not make things clearer here.

I will update my question with more information about how I setup the AAC decoder.

Comment: @Olaf, this is just how it is with COM. The documentation assumes that you are using C++, but it is a straightforward translation to C because the C++ ABI is fixed.

Comment: @AlexTelon are you sure there is only one stream? Have you processed and released all Events? Maybe it is waiting for events on the stream to be released?

Comment: @Olaf, I will try to make Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I did not want to include too much to begin with in hopes of the problem being recognisable even without the whole picture. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Olaf, In defense of Alex, C bindings are being used, and it will be extremely difficult for Alex to produce a minimal complete example in this case.  Media Foundation requires quite a bit of code.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! Im actually on my way to finish a minimal complete case with a small main method that reads a file with some of the first input I get. I just have an issue in my file reading loop atm. The whole thing is 303 lines long and excludes all error handling.. I dont know if that counts as minimal, around 300 lines is as short as I can go. That and then the input file too, but if I only include the first couple of audio frames its pretty short too.

Comment: @Ben I have now uploaded the whole context as a standalone small main program where you can see how the decoder is setup. Regarding number of streams Im sure it is only 1 stream. I have put in an if statement that warns me if I have != 1 nr of streams in or out. Regarding the comment _Maybe it is waiting for events on the stream to be released_ I am not sure what you are talking about, I have tried to look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703967(v=vs.85).aspx) and I am not sure which ones I should expect so I would know which one might be missing.

Comment: You need to check `pOutputSamples[0].pEvents` to see if it is set after the call to `ProcessOutput`. If it is set the events need to be processed and it needs to be released.

Comment: That said, I'm going to guess that you are simply not passing it valid AAC data, such that it believes it is in the middle of some operation which it requires more data to complete. As I said original "what is the decoder". This is probably an issue to do with the particular decoder and how it behaves, not about the API as such.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, the pEvents is always null though but it is good to know that is something I should handle in case it would not be.

I guess that since there does not seem to be any obvious errors in my code It makes sense to spend some more time on verifying the AAC source. Or try to find another AAC source which I could feed into my code.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben is right.  I spent some time with your code this morning, and just to test, I fed it a text file, and it produces the same results.  I was surprised that the decoder reports `MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY`.  If I were you, I would use a source reader to feed the decoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, after spending a bit of time with your code, I was able to reproduce the behavior you reported.  However, this was also true when I used arbitrary files for input.  Admittedly, I was surprised to see that the decoder reported a status of `MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY`.  Therefore, I agree with Ben regarding valid AAC data.

Instead of parsing the samples manually, perhaps you could simply use an `IMFSourceReader` to provide the samples for you, which would look similar to the following:

ERROR checking omitted for brevity

```
HRESULT configure_reader(IMFSourceReader *reader, IMFMediaType **resultingMediaType)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFMediaType *pcmMediaType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *partialType = NULL;

    // Create a partial media type that specifies uncompressed PCM audio.
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&partialType);
    hr = partialType->lpVtbl->SetGUID(partialType, &MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, &MFMediaType_Audio);
    hr = partialType->lpVtbl->SetGUID(partialType, &MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &MFAudioFormat_PCM);

    // Set this type on the source reader. The source reader will load the necessary decoder.
    hr = reader->lpVtbl->SetCurrentMediaType(reader,
                                             (DWORD) MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
                                             NULL,
                                             partialType);

    // Get the complete uncompressed format.
    hr = reader->lpVtbl->GetCurrentMediaType(reader,
                                             (DWORD) MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
                                             &pcmMediaType);

    // Ensure the stream is selected.
    hr = reader->lpVtbl->SetStreamSelection(reader,
                                            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
                                            TRUE);

    if (resultingMediaType)
    {
        *resultingMediaType = pcmMediaType;
        (*resultingMediaType)->lpVtbl->AddRef(*resultingMediaType);
    }

    (void) pcmMediaType->lpVtbl->Release(pcmMediaType);
    (void) partialType->lpVtbl->Release(partialType);

    return hr;
}

// .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .

void process_aac_audio()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFSourceReader *reader = NULL;
    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"input.aac",
                                     NULL,
                                     &reader);

    IMFMediaType *pcm_media_type = NULL;
    hr = configure_reader(reader, &pcm_media_type);
    assert(pcm_media_type);

    DWORD total_bytes = 0;
    DWORD buffer_length = 0;
    BYTE *audioData = NULL;

    IMFSample *sample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *mediaBuffer = NULL;

    while (1)
    {
        DWORD dwFlags = 0;
        hr = reader->lpVtbl->ReadSample(reader,
                                        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
                                        0,
                                        NULL,
                                        &dwFlags,
                                        NULL,
                                        &sample);

        if (FAILED(hr)) { break; }
        if (dwFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED)
        {
            printf("Type change \n");
            // TODO:
        }

        if (dwFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
        {
            printf("End of input file. \n");
            break;
        }

        if (sample == NULL)
        {
            printf("No sample \n");
            continue;
        }

        hr = sample->lpVtbl->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(sample, &mediaBuffer);
        hr = mediaBuffer->lpVtbl->Lock(mediaBuffer, &audioData, NULL, &buffer_length);
        // TODO: process buffer
        hr = mediaBuffer->lpVtbl->Unlock(mediaBuffer);
        audioData = NULL;

        total_bytes += buffer_length; // <-- update running total
        (void) sample->lpVtbl->Release(sample);
        (void) mediaBuffer->lpVtbl->Release(mediaBuffer);
    }

    if (sample)
        (void) sample->lpVtbl->Release(sample);

    if (mediaBuffer)
        (void) mediaBuffer->lpVtbl->Release(mediaBuffer);
}
```

In this case the decoder was loaded and employed for you to deliver PCM samples directly. The file you provided (input.txt) failed, however other valid aac files  worked fine.

You may be dealing with a stream instead of a file.  In that situation, create a source with code similar to the following:

```
HRESULT create_media_source(IMFByteStream *byteStream, IMFMediaSource **ppSource)
{
    MF_OBJECT_TYPE objectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;
    IMFSourceResolver* sourceResolver = NULL;
    IUnknown* source = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSourceResolver(&sourceResolver);
    hr = sourceResolver->lpVtbl->CreateObjectFromByteStream(sourceResolver,
                                                            byteStream,
                                                            NULL, // URL
                                                            MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE,
                                                            NULL, // IPropertyStore
                                                            &objectType,
                                                            &source);

    // get the IMFMediaSource interface from the media source.
    hr = source->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(source, &IID_IMFMediaSource, ppSource);
    (void) sourceResolver->lpVtbl->Release(sourceResolver);
    (void) source->lpVtbl->Release(source);
    return hr;
}
```

However, note that [CreateObjectFromByteStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704671(v=vs.85).aspx) needs a way to identify the content type.  You can either implement `IMFAttributes` [specifically `GetAllocatedString`] on your byte stream or pass in a URL

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! Good of you to test with arbitrary data. I got the same result. So it would seem that GetOutputStatus cannot be trusted in this instance. Even with error checking `hr` was never anything else than `S_OK` with uninitialised data. So I guess I cannot trust MF to tell me if I have any issues in my inputdata. @Ben might be right about the AAC data being faulty. It is difficult to compare the data to other sources since I would need to find correct LATM AAC data and be able to extract the interesting bits from a file (i.e remove file headers).

Comment: The source is not a file, but I could write the inputs I am getting to a stream. Will try it. 

But why is a stream better in this case? Less chances for me doing something wrong I guess? Or are there other inherent advantages in using a stream or a SourceReader for that matter?

Comment: Marked as accepted answer since you could show that `GetOutputStatus` produces an `MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY` even for blatantly faulty input and hence it should not be trusted (at least in this case) and the issue very well might be my input data.

Comment: @AlexTelon - stream reader is a source reader.  I included that because I thought you may need that in place of a file.  However, before using a source reader, you may want to continue trying your current solution with valid data.  That may be easiest, however a bit difficult with misleading status.

Comment: @AlexTelon - I have an idea.  What about using the example I provided (file based) to look at the data in the delivered buffer, and use it to create samples to feed your original solution?  After you get your solution working, then you can just get rid of the source reader.

Comment: You mean I should read a file and not convert to PCM but to keep it in AAC and send that data to my original solution knowing that the source is valid? Your example takes in AAC and decodes it into PCM so I guess I would need to change configure_reader to set the `partialType` to `MFAudioFormat_AAC` instead of PCM right? Or do you mean something else? I am a bit unsure about what you mean with "delivered buffer", but I take it you mean the data written to `mediaBuffer` in your example?

Comment: Oh that's right.  Good point.  You would have to change configure_reader.